# How to sort three arrays based on the order of two arrays. Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, methods

The only way I can think of is after the first sorting based on rating, I group all the names which have same rating together and sort that group based on quantity. It is a little complicated and I guess I need to implement a function to do it. Is there any shorter way to do it? Thanks.

```
// **Expected result**
//     sortedNameArray = ["b", "e", "a", "f", "c", "g", "d", "h"]
//   sortedRatingArray = [ 5,   5,   4,   3,   3,   3,   2,   2 ]
// sortedQuantityArray = [ 4,   3,   3,   5,   3,   2,   4,   3 ]


let nameArray     = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
let ratingArray   = [ 4,   5,   3,   2,   5,   3,   3,   2]
let quantityArray = [ 3,   4,   3,   4,   3,   5,   2,   3]

let firstNameArray = Array(zip(nameArray, ratingArray)).sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }
let firstRatingArray = Array(zip(ratingArray, ratingArray)).sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }
let firstQuantityArray = Array(zip(quantityArray, ratingArray)).sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }

// first sorting based on rating
firstNameArray      // = ["b", "e", "a", "c", "f", "g", "d", "h"]
firstRatingArray    // = [5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]
firstQuantityArray  // = [4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3]

// second sorting based on quantity.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than maintaining three arrays that require synchronization, just maintain a single array of a simple struct.

```
struct Entry {
    let name: String
    let rating: Int
    let quantity: Int
}

let entries = [ Entry(name: "a", rating: 4, quantity: 3),
                Entry(name: "b", rating: 5, quantity: 4),
                Entry(name: "c", rating: 3, quantity: 3),
                Entry(name: "d", rating: 2, quantity: 4),
                Entry(name: "e", rating: 5, quantity: 3),
                Entry(name: "f", rating: 3, quantity: 5),
                Entry(name: "g", rating: 3, quantity: 2),
                Entry(name: "h", rating: 2, quantity: 3),
]

let sortedEntries = entries.sort { lhs, rhs in
    if lhs.rating != rhs.rating {
        return lhs.rating > rhs.rating
    }

    return lhs.quantity > rhs.quantity
}
```

With this, your algorithms should become trivial and require less computation.

If you require separate arrays at some point, it's trivial to unzip it (though I seldom find this necessary in practice):

```
let nameArray = entries.map { $0.name }
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide more codes that can solve the example I provided? Thanks.

Comment: @PakHoCheung Just make a single array of type `[Entry]`. If you let the `Entry` struct conform to the `Comparable` protocol, you'll be able to sort them pretty easily.

Comment: OK. let me take a look at the swift library first. Didn't use struct before.

Comment: `Comparable` probably isn't the right tool here. This is just one reasonable sort order for `Entry`. It's not the only way you'd want to sort them (`Comparable` forces you to choose one-and-only-one sort order). Instead, you use the version of `sort` that takes an `isOrderedBefore` function.

Comment: What if the arrays of rating, name and quantity are appended from server? I guess I cannot manually set something like Entry(name: "a", rating: 4, quantity: 3). What should I do based on this case?

Comment: can I first set it like let entries = [] . Then, entries.append(Entry(name: (from server), rating: (from server), quantity: (from server)))

Comment: `entries` would have to be a `var` property (since you modify it), but yes. I suspect you need to take a step back and start with the basics: https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/swift